# Louis XIV of France, "L'État, c'est moi", and the royal 'we'

Tags: france, quotes

(Maybe should be in the French Language community instead.)
Louis XIV famously allegedly said "L'État, c'est moi". But wouldn't he (at least hypothetically) have used the royal 'we', i.e., "L'État, c'est nous"?

(I ask partly because, if the use of the royal 'we' would be correct, it could be taken as evidence he never said "L'État...".)

I'm aware of a related question ([Did Louis XIV actually say "The State? I am the State."? Could he have said it?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/10085/did-louis-xiv-actually-say-the-state-i-am-the-state-could-he-have-said-it)) but that doesn't address the specific wording.

Comment: A more collaborative/conciliatory royal might use the royal 'we', but a royal who sees themselves as the one & only authority would use "I" so that it would be understood by all who was in power. In modern parlance, we have the management buzz term, "there is no 'I' in team". Also, this question is not about history, it's more about language & how it is used to convey power.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is more about language & how it can be used to convey power

Comment: Does French have a royal "we", or is that just an English affectation?

Comment: HorusKol - I know that German does.  When Francis Joseph became Austrian emperor in 1848, the year of revolutions, there was a joke that the "wir" or "we" in his proclamations stood for Windischgraetz, Jellac, and Radetsky, three generals fighting the rebels.  But German is closer to English than French is.  The Wikipedia article indicates the royal we is widespread in Europe. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_we

Comment: If he had said, *L'Etat c'est nous*, it wouldn't convey the idea properly. To effectively say that the State was embodied in his person, he needed to make it unambiguous, and explicitly exclude ministers, court personal, generals, justices, etc.

Comment: I was going to post this in the French Language community, but the tags, and many of the questions and answers, are in French. Perhaps there a more general language community. Anyway, the meaning and implications of the royal we are certainly of historical import.

Answer (score 0):

I know that German does. When Francis Joseph became Austrian emperor in 1848, the year of revolutions, there was a joke that the "wir" or "we" in his proclamations stood for Windischgraetz, Jellac, and Radetsky, three generals fighting the rebels. But German is closer to English than French is. The Wikipedia article indicates the royal we is widespread in Europe.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_we[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_we)

And here is a discussions that mentions its use in French, Spanish, German:

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/majestic-plural-or-the-royal-we-pluralis-majestatis.1091632/[2](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/majestic-plural-or-the-royal-we-pluralis-majestatis.1091632/)

And this site says:

> Queen Elizabeth I certainly used it, as did many Russian rulers and French rulers.

http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-the-royal-we.htm[3](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-the-royal-we.htm)

Thus I think nous would be used as the royal we in French.